# C++ Cannot edit items of a vector inside a static vector after creating it

Tags: c++, object, vector

I have been trying to solve this issue without success, I hope that someone can help me to fix it.

I have a class Constants with a vector of objects of type A:

```
class Constants
{

public:
    static std::vector<A> currentA;
}
```

The class A has this constructor and the function `getB()` that returns _b:

```
A::A(std::vector<B>& b)
{
    _b=b;
}
```

and the class B is like this:

```
class B
{
private:
     int Age;

public:

     B(const int& age){Age = age;};
     int getAge(){return Age;};
     void setAge(const int& age){Age=age;}

}
```

And that's it. If I add an item to currentA like this:

```
 std::vector<B> bList;
 playerList.push_back(B(5));
 Constants::currentA.push_back(bList);
```

the value 5 is returned if you do `Constants::currentA.getB().at(0).getAge();`,
but if you do:

```
 Constants::currentA.getB().at(0).setAge(10);
```

and then:

```
Constants::currentA.getB().at(0).getAge();
```

it still returns 5.

Any ideas??

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you include the implementation of getB?

Comment: You haven't provided a complete example. My guess: `getB` returns a *copy*. you need a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return `_b` by value from `getB()`.

When you `setAge()` you do it on a local copy, which then gets forgotten.

The solution is to define getB() as resturning a reference to the vector instead of the vector itself.

Comment: So basically at getB() i would only need to put & like this? : 
  std::vector<B>& getB();

i am a c++ noob hehe

EDIT: yes this solved the problem. THANKYOU so much

thank you!